# How to comprehend inline, const and reference in a function declaration?

Tags: c++, function, reference, inline, declaration

I noticed a function declaration in my program which included `inline, const and reference(&)` before the function name. It is easy to follow each of the keywords separately, but can anyone explain the overall meaning when they are used together?

```
inline const std::string& foo()
{
}
```

I'm new to CPP programming. Ah, putting so many keywords doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: The meaning of those combined keywords is simply the sum of the meanings of the individual keywords. I'm not entirely sure what is confusing you. Is there something contradictory about the meanings of the keywords when put together?

Comment: @cigien Yeah, you are correct, I was just not sure how to visualize in such situation, hope you get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `const std::string&`
  This is the return type of the function, which is a reference to a constant `std::string`.
- [`inline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline)
  This means that this function may be defined multiple times, but you are sure that those definitions are identical and the linker may keep one of those definitions and discard the rest. You usually use this when placing the function definition in a header file, which is included by multiple cpp files, and would have invalidated [One Definition Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Because C++ is very much a free-form language where one could add any number of white-space between operators, keywords and symbols, we could write the function like this instead (with helpful comments):

```
inline              // Hint for the compiler that it's allowed to inline the function
const std::string&  // Function return type, a reference to a constant std::string
foo                 // Function name
()                  // Function arguments, none
{
    // Empty body, not correct since the function is supposed to return something
}
```

Note that `inline` is only a hint that the compiler is allowed "inline" the function (basically copy-paste the generated code instead of doing an actual function call). The compiler is allowed to inline function calls anyway, and [the `inline` keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) have some other implications in regards to [linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Linkage).

Comment: Thanks, just curious about the added benefit of returning reference type?

Comment: @AadilHoda That really depends on the problem the function is supposed to solve. There's no generic answer for that.